# Add a default value to textbox by Javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am trying to add the value to text box but I don't where I am making mistakes. Can you guys help with this. I cannot add the default value in HTML Tag itself.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtfirstName").val("Your First Name Here!"); 
        $("input[id='txtlastName']").val("Your Last Name Here!"); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="txtfirstName" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="txtlastName">

</body>
</html>
```

**FYI: This is just an example page.**

Please guide me with this. If this post is not related please don't degrade. Just let me know, I will delete it.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, for starters, you'll need to surround your Javascript with `<script> // your code here </script>`

Comment: Check out the placeholder attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp, and in terms of your JQuery, $('#txtfirstName') will do, no need to say input. Along with that, add <script> tags as pmahomme mentioned

Comment: @Ted OP said they can't add value to the HTML tag itself.

Comment: Look at my example:)

Comment: @Ted I tried doing that and I have changed above code and test both the ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encase your JavaScript in a script tag.  The following code does what you want:

```
<script   
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   
    integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="     
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtfirstName").val("Your First Name Here!");
        $("input[id='txtlastName']").val("Your Last Name Here!");
    });
</script>
<body>


  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="txtfirstName" />
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="txtlastName" />


<p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>

<p>Also note that the default width of a text input field is 20 characters.</p>

</body>
```

Also, I changed the way JQuery looks for one of the inputs, so you can see another way of doing it.

EDIT: 
If you want to do it not using JQuery, the following will do it in plain JavaScript.  It uses an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to encapsulate the load function, so extraneous variables and functions to populate the global object (the window object).

```
<script>
  (function () {
    function init () {
      document.getElementById("txtfirstName").value = "Your First Name Here!"
      document.getElementById("txtlastName").value = "Your Last Name Here!"
    }
    window.onload = init;
  }())
</script>
```

Comment: Tried but it did not appear on the text box as default value. Instead it is giving me this error. [Image Reference](https://s10.postimg.org/qp7g8hts9/temp_16.png)

Comment: one sec and I'll fix it

Comment: I added in the reference to the JQuery library.

Comment: That work thank you very much. But curious to know that if I do not want to add `<script   
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   
    integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="     
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`. Is there any other way to add Value or placeholder?

Comment: yep one sec, and I'll make it so you don't have to

Comment: I've updated it and added code which shows how to do it without JQuery

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value via JavaScript then you have to do it with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value = 'test';
```

The problem in your case is that you are using JQuery and I can't see an integration of the jQuery source in your case. You have to decide whether you want to d o it with JavaScript or jQuery.

With JavaScript you don't need an external framework but I would prefer jQuery over JavaScript because it is more powerful.

This would be a full example in JavaScript (no framework needed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    document.getElementById('txtfirstName').value = 'test';

</script>
</head>

<body>

First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="txtfirstName">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="txtlastName">


</body>
</html>
```

With jQuery the same looks like this (integration of the framework in the first line):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#txtfirstName").text("Hello world!");

});
</script>
```

So you can see that jQuery is much simpler and it uses less code then JavaScript.

See it working in this JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Anokrize/aemy4nea/

Comment: I don't want onlick function that's the reason I didn't add any button.

Comment: Then just remove the click function and the button @user3338497

Comment: See it now @user3338497